# How to prevent a socket connection from disconnecting immediately

Tags: javascript, sockets, socket.io, connection, multiplayer

In my game, once a player has connected, their socket disconnects. When they leave the game, the socket disconnects again. This is very bad as it is hard to distinguish between a *fake* disconnect and a real one (to remove the player from the list of online players)

This "fake" disconnect doesn't affect any communication though. The game works as normal, except that the server receives a disconnect event just after a player joins. Is there any way to fix this?